# How can I prevent my furnace vent from icing up and shutting off the furnace?

Tags: ventilation

How do I keep my exhaust vent from icing up in the winter. We are in a new house with a HE Furnace in a pretty cold zone. It has iced up two times now and we are only in our 1st winter. Anything I can do to help prevent this?

Comment: Pictures if the vent termination outside will greatly help in finding a solution to the issue

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is insulate the exhaust vent all the way to the outlet. The warmer the air is when it gets to the opening, the more likely it won't freeze. Does it pass through any unconditioned spaces on the way to its outlet? If so insulate it the whole way from the furnace as best as you can.. Keep that 85f degree exhaust air as warm as possible on its journey to the freezing cold..